# How to extract objectbox database in browser?

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I have implemented database with objectbox but now I want to see database in browser i.e. chrome. But I don't know how to extract that. If anyone know that please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Referral link : https://docs.objectbox.io/android

Comment: This? https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser

Comment: Thanks for your answer Markus. I have implemented the steps but somehow I am getting error regarding library of objectbrowser.

Comment: If you'd be more specific, someone might be able to help you.